# Does each thread have its own stack?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, stack

When I create multiple threads from a process, then does each thread have its own stack, or is it that they share the stack of their parent process. What happens when a thread makes a system call? Do threads also maintain their own kernel stack like processes?

Comment: yes thread specific stack!, global values are share-able among thread (local not)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What happens when we make a system call from a thread?

Comment: for example if you call `open()` system call to open a file. using `int f = open()` then of-course `f` is local to thread. but remember the file descriptors are shared between the threads.  If you know the value of `f` then you can use that value in different thread to access same file (you don't need to open again)

Comment: [Each thread has a reserved region of memory referred to as its stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation).

Comment: Note: there is no such thing as a stack or a kernel in the C++ Standard; those are implementation details... which depend on your C++ implementation and OS of choice. So what C++ implementation and OS are you talking about ? gcc & Linux ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Is it different with C and C++ ?

Comment: @LidongGuo: For interoperability reasons, it better not be different. That being said, since it's implementation-defined, an implementation could make it different...

Comment: @MatthieuM. The standard doesn't use the word "stack", but the semantics of function call that it defines definitely requires one.  And C++11 requires that each thread have its own stack.

Comment: @LidongGuo No.  Thread semantics are one thing on which the two committees collaborated.  (The interfaces vary somewhat, since C obviously cannot provide "objects" for threads, mutex, etc., but the semantics are identical.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes threads have their own stacks and their own kernel stacks (e.g. linux).

When a thread makes a system call, you trap into kernel mode (from user mode), you pass the arguments to the kernel, the arguments are checked, the kernel does w/e it needs to do (in the kernel stack), returns the final value back to the thread and you go back to user mode.

Comment: How does the kernel do "w/e it needs to do" without a stack?

Comment: I'll clarify in my answer

Comment: The kernel stack is just a security precaution added onto a preexisting model. Multiple stacks are a prerequisite to multithreading. The kernel essentially provides a parallel version of whatever is happening in user space to prevent sensitive data from leaking out.

Comment: @Potatoswatter How does a kernel thread improve security? It's my understanding that it is designed that way for performance.